# How to add a constraint file to environment.yml for conda?

Tags: python, pip, airflow, conda

I'm currently trying to set up a conda environment which has Apache Airflow in it.
The tricky part about Apache Airflow is that it has a lot of constraints and the recommended way to install it is using pip and the constraints that the project supplies.
I would like have an `environment.yml` so that it is easier to setup the project on a server later.
I tried to have the following `environment.yml`:

```
name: project_name
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python==3.9
  - pip
  - pip:
      - poetry
      - apache-airflow==2.6.2 --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.6.2/constraints-3.9.txt"
```

But pip didn't pick up the constraints and installed the lastest pydantic (2.x something) which isn't compatible with Airflow.
Eventually, I had to make this hacky solution.

```
name: project_name
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python==3.9
  - pip
  - pip:
      - -r requirements.txt
```

And `requirements.txt` was:

```
-c airflow-constraints.txt
poetry
apache-airflow==2.6.2
```

And then `airflow-constraints.txt` had the contents of the constraints file.

Is there a simpler way to get this behaviour without having to resort to multiple requirements files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a totally shower thought moment, I realised what could work.

Instead of the ugly and fragmented requirements and constraints in different files. I could get conda and pip to run with the following:

```
name: project_name
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python==3.9
  - pip
  - pip:
      - -c "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.6.2/constraints-3.9.txt"
      - poetry
      - apache-airflow==2.6.2
```

This registered the constraints with pip, and saved me from the fragmented requirements, constraints and environment files.

Turns out conda simply creates a temporary requirements file (like so `condaenv.rt8dkvth.requirements.txt`) with the contents of the `pip:` command in the `environment.yml` file and then runs `pip install` with that file.